# SQL Server procedure recompile

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I have a question: let's say I have a procedure which contains dynamic SQL inside the definition of procedure, so when I execute the procedure for the first time, it's obvious that it compiles the procedure and stores the plan for first time.

What happens during the second run? Will the same plan be used or will the procedure go for a recompile as it contains dynamic SQL in it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A similar question has already been answered in Stack Exchange for Database Administrators. Please refer: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/47283/when-does-sp-executesql-refresh-the-query-plan

Comment: Thanks for the details

Comment: @AdarshHDDev, please accept or upvote the answer, if it's useful.

Comment: Hi  Bala, i have already voted up the answer, since am new and my reputation is below 15.  The voting is not showing for public :(

Answer (score 1):

Dynamic SQL is always compiled. It may result in the same execution plan as the first run (totally dependent on parameters).

I would suggest reading [this article](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc966425.aspx) from MS. Relevant quotes:

> Recompilations: Definition
>
> Before a query, batch, stored procedure, trigger, prepared statement, or dynamic SQL statement (henceforth, "batch") begins execution on a SQL Server, the batch gets compiled into a plan. The plan is then executed for its effects or to produce results.

and

> Compiled plans are stored into a part of SQL Server's memory called plan cache . Plan cache is searched for possible plan reuse opportunities. If a plan reuse for a batch happens, its compilation costs are avoided.